# Yii2 gridview widget how to show value in place of ids (foreign keys)

Tags: gridview, view, yii2

I am having three foreign keys in a table, records of which I am showing using kartik gridview widget, I want to display the value in place of the foreign key showing over there by default, can anybody help me where to make changes to get this.
I have used Ajax Crud Generator for generating the forms and view.

Comment: You question is not clear ... you mean that need  to show the related  value of tbales related  by a foreign key inside the main table  ?  if  you need  this you can see http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/  for a complete management include filter and sorting

Comment: Simply I want to show values (say Country name) in place of (fk Country Id) in my profile table gridview (where country id is fk in profile table), I have used Ajax Crud Generator to generate the CRUD for profile.

Comment: the link proposed  in based su php  .. if you need  ajax  .you mean that you are using  a editable gridview  ??? .. you should explain better you question and add  the related  code ..

Comment: you can fetch like this 

     forignkey_column_name0->display_colum_name

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this,I dont know about  kartik gridview widget, but this is normal grid view

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1215

Comment: I just want the value in gridview in place of foreign key value in the view of the table.

Comment: you cant see this link

Answer (score 0):

In the model which is having the foreign keys define the relation in the rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
           [['added_by'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['added_by' => 'id']],


    ];
}
```

Add a method in the model itself:

```
public function getAddedUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'added_by']);
}
```

Now going in the grid view, define the custom attribute as:

```
['attribute' => 'vendor_id', 'format'=>'raw', 'value' => function($model){
                                return $model->addedUser->company_name;
                        }],
```

Hope this may help you to understand. Thanks.